# Do not display closed or duplicate question on landing pages

Tags: feature-request

This isn't a question of "why are there so many closed questions". This is User experience.

I counted 13 closed questions on the landing page for Programmers Stack exchange. On StackOverflow, I see none.

I do not frequent Programmers Exchange, but this user experience is horrible! I honestly did not want to use the site, because it was so hard to find a real question that I could contribute to.

Can we please just not display closed or duplicate questions on the landing page?

Comment: "On StackOverflow, I see none." - That's because it moves so fast that they haven't been closed *yet*. :P

Comment: Have you tried the [unanswered page](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/unanswered)?

Comment: @Mysticial Whatever the case, it is a much better user experience!

Comment: @Mysticial Stack Overflow's home page shows "interesting" questions, not the active questions in reverse chronological order like every other site.

Comment: @AnnaLear Ah... I never realized that. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey if I have to go look for the unanswered page from _the landing page_ to find real questions, doesn't that show something is lacking in user experience?

Comment: I suppose, if you count the additional single click you have to make as a problem with the user experience.

Comment: @RobertHarvey besides the additional click, if I am a new user I will not necessarily know to even go to unanswered.

Comment: Did you know? It's fairly prominently displayed at the top of the page.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I honestly did not

Comment: @stevebot: "*if I am a new user I will not necessarily know to even go to unanswered*" If you're a new user... how do we know that you want to find *unanswered questions* at all? Answering questions is not the *only* reason to visit a SE site.

Comment: @NicolBolas It's not about unanswered. A new user shouldn't have to see so many [closed] and [duplicate] questions. It doesn't encourage them to ask questions. Maybe SE is intended to be hard for new users, is that the case?

Comment: If a new user sees [closed] and [duplicate] questions on the landing page, then hopefully, it will encourage some of them to understand what they are and why they are closed. That can only be a huge positive for *everybody's* user experience, no?

Comment: @RivieraKid Yes,that would be a positive. No, it is not friendly to new users.

Comment: Hrrmm if you think the landing page on Programmers is bad, you probably don't want to frequent their [newest questions page](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest). It averages anywhere from 30-50% closed/downvoted on most days. There's even a [meta post](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5379/1130) containing exact stats as of the beginning of this year: over 50% of their questions from the past 60 days were closed, deleted, or downvoted below 0.

Comment: Being friendly to new users is one possible means to an end, not the end itself. You can make the argument that if a new user can't bothered to familiarise themselves with the site to know what questions are and are not acceptable, then do we really want them clogging up the site with "bad" or duplicate questions? I know I don't. The network is here for great questions and answers - we won't get those by leaving any old rubbish on the sites without consequence, but leaving them visible is *explicitly* telling new users what we **don't** want to see. Setting boundaries is **not** unfriendly.

Comment: @RivieraKid Well said. It's been so long since I joined SE that I can't remember what the account creation process is like. Are new users instructed on the SE flagging and review process?

Comment: Not sure about flagging and reviewing but new users are forced to read a quick tutorial when they ask their first question (admittedly you can just click through it), and are pointed at the FAQ (which does, of course, include info on flagging, closing, how to ask, etc), so they are given the opportunity to learn, if they want to. That is probably the biggest reason the community may seem to be unfriendly - we've already tried to help them learn and some people ignore it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I disagree.

Closed questions aren't dead. There are more ways to contribute than just answers. When a question is edited it is sent back to the home page, which means it can be reviewed by others and possibly be re-opened, or even edited again. Users with less then 2000 reputation can even gain more reputation by doing so.

Hiding them simply means the chances of these questions being re-opened become close to impossible. Not everyone spends time in the review queues contrary to the common belief that they do.

To expand, and having given this some more thought, it also helps new users understand that duplicates do get closed, and that questions that don't meet a certain standard do get closed. They should learn from these questions and what not to ask.

Comment: In my experience, the resurrection of closed questions is the exception, not the norm. I like my ui to cater to the _norm_ not the _exception_.

Comment: @stevebot It's not just a matter of what the UI *caters to*. The UI has a substantial effect on *what the norm is.*

Comment: @stevebot Again I disagree. Quite a number of posts get reopened if the OP's or community put in some effort. There is no exceptions in SE. Closed and duplicate posts is part of the norm. It's one of the features that make SE sites successful.

Comment: @Diago and EliahKagan thanks, these  are the first real answers I have heard here. SE is intentionally hard for new users, so that it can set the norm for them. Makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to do filtering process on this site,

from all questions close and duplicate questions filter and not visible for anyone who find answer of his/her query.

but its not possible because of duplicate and close question sometime some small mistake if its edited and correct this mistake its not bad.

Comment: What I clearly stated I wanted is to not display these questions on the _landing page_, where new users are dropped. Seasoned users should be able to access and edit [closed] or [duplicate] questions somewhere else (seasoned users are familiar with the edit process, whereas new users are likely not).

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it might be more of a conversation for programmers meta than for the general meta.  That having been said, Why not put a (low... 25 or 50 or so) rep requirement for seeing closed questions?  That should reduce the scare-away-new-users issue a bit, and the newest users don't have a whole lot to do with closed questions anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even realize there was a programmers meta! Even after 3 years, I am still a new user, maybe that is my problem -_-.